# Value object design rules in ddd

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, aggregate, value-objects

My question is simple, lets say that i have a `Car` entity that has `Number` value object, and a `Truck` entity that have a `Number` value object also,

do this mean that i have one value object in my app named `Number` for both entities as shared value object ?

or that is up to what make the `Number` valid for each entity ?

Comment: Please don't use abbreviations (or at least explain them) and a code example would certainly aid your question.

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Value objects by definition are immutable and should be possible to be shared safely. It has NO identity. I can recommend the book Domain Driven Design by Eric Evans (Chapter 5 explains the concepts in detail). Also please see an [article](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/EvansClassification.html) by Martin Fowler

Answer (score 0):

> "do this mean that i have one value object in my app named Number for
>   both entities as shared value object ?"

`Number` could be a **shared concept** if they both fundamentally represent the same thing as per your Ubiquitous Language. If they do not, then a distinction is required such as `CarNumber` and `TruckNumber` (e.g. both require a different format).

One note though, the context alone if well defined is usually enough to avoid term overloading, therefore you will rarely end up with things such as `UserAccount` and `BankAccount` in a Bounded Context (BC) and if you do then your BC boundaries are most likely wrong.

However, I believe there's something slightly different about `Number`. Because it is a well known mathematical concept and that it is very likely that some mathematical numbers will be used in your domain, I would suggest to be a bit more descriptive to avoid confusion, perhaps `VehiculeNumber`?

Answer (score 0):

First, Value objects - like most ddd implements - should be modeled to address some part of the ubiquitous language of your domain.

When to create a Value Object? In the book `Implementing Domain Driven Design`, Vaughn Vernon gives these characteristics of a Value Object

- It measures, quantifies, or describes a thing in the domain.
- It
  can be maintained as immutable.
- It models a conceptual whole by
  composing related attributes as an integral unit.
- It is completely
  replaceable when the measurement or description changes.
- It can be
  compared with others using Value equality.
- It supplies its
  collaborators with Side-Effect-Free Behavior

The first bulletin means that a VO should measure, quantify, or describe a thing in the domain.

Next, it should be immutable, and should not have state changing methods. That also goes for any objects inside the VO, they too must never be able to change if the VO uses them.

Moving on, a VO must be complete after construction. That means all of its attributes and properties that it needs must be in a valid state. Example: A price VO must set both `currency` and `amount` properties with correct values in the constructor.

Replicability. This means that a VO can be replaced with another VO of the same type. If your VO can set `currency` to Yen as opposed to Dollar then this might become a problem when later trying to replace the the VO because you want to change(replace) the `amount` for `price`.

Example: an Entity accepts the VO `Price` which has a `currency` of Dollar and an `amount` of 100,000. If we could construct a new VO of the same type with `currency` of Yen and an `amount` of 200,000 then this VO might not be replaceable. This will depend on your domain of course, but if the Entity's intent is to simply replace the monetary value of the VO only, then it might be better to have separate `DollarVO` and `YenVO` to avoid creating a VO with an impedance mismatch of properties.

Comparison: VO's should be comparable to other VO instances of the same type. If a VO can be constructed with the `currency` property but in other cases it is not, then this would potentially violate comparability. IE. you should be able to take two instances of the same VO and compare their properties checking for different values of those properties only. If a property is missing then the comparison fails for the wrong reason.

The last principle is parcel to Immutability. If you're gonna give VO's methods, then make sure they ain't changing nothing.